# Aligning individual columns in pandas to_latex

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I'm using the `pandas` `to_latex` method to convert a dataframe into a latex `tabular`. I don't see an option to change the alignment fields of the resulting tabular. For example, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
    Number of days  Tuples Distinct Tuples
162             29  700587           41300
163             20  497599           29302
164             15  365599           21382
165             10  256903           14916
166              5  127647            7441
167              2   54254            3117
168              1   26987            1288
```

and my output table looks like this:

```
In [50]: print df.to_latex(index=None)
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Number of days &  Tuples & Distinct Tuples \\
\midrule
            29 &  700587 &           41300 \\
            20 &  497599 &           29302 \\
            15 &  365599 &           21382 \\
            10 &  256903 &           14916 \\
             5 &  127647 &            7441 \\
             2 &   54254 &            3117 \\
             1 &   26987 &            1288 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

What I want is for the `{lll}` alignment to change to `{rrr}`. In general, I might even want different alignments for different columns, or even use a vertical separator | in a `{r|r|r}` designator.

Is this currently supported ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in code of pandas(this function is used for rendering latex_table):
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/format.py#L492
There's not supported yet. Only if your data is numpy's number it will be formatted to right. In python it's pretty easy to format your columns.

```
print df.to_latex(index=None).replace('lll','rrr')
```

or in more generic way using regex replace.

Answer (score 13):

By now (`pandas` version 0.17.1), the `to_latex` method has the `column_format` parameter, so you could simply do

```
print df.to_latex(index=None, column_format='rrr')
```